# My Nginx Server static content displayed 403 forbidden error. Why?

Tags: nginx, flask

I deployed my flask app with gunicorn and I make nginx serve the static content. The .conf file is like that

```
server {
        listen  80;
        listen  [::]:80;

        server_name     lab01.net;

        location /static {
                alias   /home/lab01/blog/flaskblog/static;
                autoindex       on;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass      http://localhost:8000;
                proxy_redirect  off;
        }


}
```

I think the configuration is right but when I access the static file in browser http://lab01.net/static , 403 forbidden error is found.

And then I check the nginx log file and the log file keep saying that

```
2021/09/19 19:45:18 [error] 86998#0: *7 "/home/lab01/blog/flaskblog/static/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied), client: 192.168.89.1, server: lab01.net, request: "GET /static/ HTTP/1.1", host: "lab01.net"
```

In the log file it said **/home/lab01/blog/flaskblog/static/index.html** is forbidden. Why is it keep saying like that? Why is the server accessing the index.html? In the static folder there are only Images and css files. ***Is it supposed to access these files instead of index.html???***

> Note: When I first deployed on the server the static content are
> displayed correctly and there is no errors. After I switch all the codebase to
> another server and reconfigure the nginx. I encounter this error. All the firewall and SeLinux fcontext and boolean are configured as well.

Comment: In the [docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/) it says that you should end the location with a `/`, like: `location /static/ {`

Comment: When I add location /static/ {  - the error log said 2021/09/19 20:12:42 [error] 87465#0: *1 "/home/lab01/blog/flaskblog/staticindex.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied), Behind the static index.html is added like that in error log file it displays like this "staticindex.html". I don't know what the hell is wrong with my server and why Nginx is so obsessed with index.html. LOL

Comment: If you see `"staticindex.html"` and think of `"static/index.html"`, would it then be smart to add a `/` to the end of your `alias` line (before the `;`)?

Comment: I finllay figured out the problem. I move all of my codebase under root directory and it resolved the error but I don't know why. All the file permission ( 755 to all dirs) and ownership(nginx:nginx) are the same both under /home/lab01 and root (/). But when the codebase dir is under /home/lab01 (user home directory) it keeps saying 403 permission denied error, but when it's under root dir(/), Nginx can display all the static contents. That's a real pain. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: [nginx 403 Forbidden Error hosting in User Home Directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/416787/nginx-403-forbidden-error-hosting-in-user-home-directory)